# Cycling Through List of URLs

Tags: excel, vba

This code works great when cycling through URLs such as google, yahoo, ect
But I am really trying to cycle through web pages as shown here.

```
\\FMC9050101\Proj\6513_OAK3\Jobads\slide1.htm
\\FMC9050101\Proj\6513_OAK3\Jobads\slide2.htm
\\FMC9050101\Proj\6513_OAK3\Jobads\slide3.htm
```

The 1st webpage opens up perfect, but I get and Automation Error, "The object invoked has disconnected from its clients" on this line, as the next page is cycled in... the idea is to replace the existing page without opening a new tab.

```
While .Busy Or .ReadyState <> 4: DoEvents: Wend
```

**** Code ***

```
Dim wsSheet As Worksheet, Rows As Long, links As Variant, IE As Object, link As Variant
Set wb = ThisWorkbook
Set wsSheet = wb.Sheets("Sheet1")

Set IE = New InternetExplorer

Rows = wsSheet.Cells(wsSheet.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
links = wsSheet.Range("A1:A" & Rows)

With IE
    .Visible = True
    For Each link In links
        .navigate (link)
        While .Busy Or .ReadyState <> 4: DoEvents: Wend
        MsgBox .Document.body.innerText
    Next link
End With
```

Comment: Did you try opening the problematic links manually in IE browser? See what's happening, then fix

Comment: Yes, thank you, these 3 webpages are all good pages, slides 1,2 & 3.  Somehow the object (webpage I think) is disconnecting, but it does not when I use https web pages?

Answer (score 0):

Okay, changed the strategy where I am reading the list of URLs from a server verses an excel sheet which is where I was going with this after the other issues were sorted out.  Using an Admin account, this version works perfectly.

```
Sub Run_SlideShow()
'
Dim x As Integer
Dim wsSheet As Worksheet, Rows As Long, links As Variant, IE As Object, link 
As Variant
Dim FilePath As String, Filter As String, F As Variant, I As Integer
'
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.EnableEvents = True
'
Set wb = ThisWorkbook
Set wsSheet = wb.Sheets("Sheet2")
Filter = "*.htm"
Set IE = CreateObject("Internetexplorer.Application")
IE.Visible = False
FilePath = "\\FMC9050101\PROJ\6513_OAK3\Jobads"

For x = 1 To 9999 ' run for 30 hours, use scheduled task to kill excel and 
restart every 24 hours
'
ArrFile = GetFileList(FilePath + "\" + Filter)
Select Case IsArray(ArrFile)
Case True
For I = LBound(ArrFile) To UBound(ArrFile)
    F = ArrFile(I)
    link = (FilePath & "\" & F)
    IE.Navigate link
    IE.Visible = True
    'Application.StatusBar = "Loading " & link
    Do While IE.Busy
        Application.Wait DateAdd("s", 2, Now) ' set slide time here
    Loop
Next
Case False 'no files found
        MsgBox "No matching files"
End Select
Next x
'
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
Application.EnableEvents = True
'
Set IE = Nothing
Application.StatusBar = ""
'
End Sub
```